# The list of items I scrape from a webpage differs from the source of the page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a list of zpids from this [webpage](https://www.zillow.com/ct/9_p/) using the requests module. The zpids are available within a list right next to `searchListZpids` in the page source (ctrl + u). They are 40 in number.

The script below can fetch the zpids errorlessly. However, the problem is the list the script produces are different from the ones available on that webpage. Some of the zpids in the list I received have exact matchings with those available on that page.

Sometimes the list I get is accurate but most of the time they are different.

The script that I'm using:

```
import re
import requests

link = 'https://www.zillow.com/ct/9_p/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
zpids = re.findall(r"searchListZpids[\s\S]+?\[(.*?)\]",res.text)[0]
print(zpids)
```

Output I get at this moment:

```
57912175, 177202011, 57838346, 57702376, 2083150985, 2091636205, 59028017, 2066602375, 57843835, 2066598335, 58845027, 58904562, 58118011, 58838731, 57930222, 2066611590, 59977275, 197747278, 57932219, 57893209, 58775017, 2066600444, 2066601022, 58059157, 177275234, 58819070, 59297439, 58859881, 2078457589, 58775318, 57790587, 57689409, 2066601997, 57394605, 177286302, 58133143, 59068957, 58096934, 240506947, 83121293
```

How can I scrape the exact list of zpids from that webpage using requests?

EDIT:

I thought to further clarify the whereabouts of the list of pids I wish to extract from that site's page source. After navigating to this [link](https://www.zillow.com/ct/9_p/), when you press `Ctrl + U`, you should see the page source in a different tab. Now, press `ctrl + f` and write `searchListZpids` in the search bar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnpZE.jpg). This time you should see the list of pids right next to `searchListZpids` in that page, which is more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7do4O.jpg). This is the very list what I wish to extract. Sometimes the list the above script produces is identical to the ones available in the page source but most of the time they are different.

Comment: How does the result differ? What is missing with it?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I scrape the exact list of zpids from that webpage using requests?

Try following pattern to get exactly the list

```
zpids = re.findall(r"searchListZpids[\s\S]+?(\[.*?\])", res.text)[0]
zpids = eval(zpids)

print(zpids)
```

Output:

> [57893930, 58081832, 58860541, 58890802, 69057773, 210140012, 58913561, 58820158, 82973247, 197791135, 58838105, 2066643456, 57784503, 210141981, 57312365, 58776838, 58859881, 60103968, 58088978, 333569598, 58952600, 177281260, 2066618828, 2066555488, 57246785, 57336201, 58960631, 58042110, 58028998, 174037330, 60005139, 174072877, 210140037, 210145877, 57248627, 57278888, 57330507, 57958372, 174447170, 58875088]

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code several times and not found a mismatch once.

t.py file

```
import re
import requests

link = 'https://www.zillow.com/ct/9_p/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
zpids = re.findall(r"searchListZpids[\s\S]+?\[(.*?)\]",res.text)[0]
print(zpids)
with open("html.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(res.text)
    f.write("\n")
```

in terminal

```
date && python3 t.py>1 && perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /searchListZpids\",\"\[((.*?))\]\"/' html.txt>2 && diff 1 2 && rm html.txt 1 2
```

output

```
(.picamenv) anupamkumar@m1 lib % date && python3 t.py>1 && perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /searchListZpids\",\"\[((.*?))\]\"/' html.txt>2 && diff 1 2 && rm html.txt 1 2
Thu Jan 27 13:08:11 EST 2022
(.picamenv) anupamkumar@m1 lib % date && python3 t.py>1 && perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /searchListZpids\",\"\[((.*?))\]\"/' html.txt>2 && diff 1 2 && rm html.txt 1 2
Thu Jan 27 13:08:13 EST 2022
(.picamenv) anupamkumar@m1 lib % date && python3 t.py>1 && perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /searchListZpids\",\"\[((.*?))\]\"/' html.txt>2 && diff 1 2 && rm html.txt 1 2
Thu Jan 27 13:08:15 EST 2022
(.picamenv) anupamkumar@m1 lib % date && python3 t.py>1 && perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /searchListZpids\",\"\[((.*?))\]\"/' html.txt>2 && diff 1 2 && rm html.txt 1 2
Thu Jan 27 13:08:17 EST 2022
(.picamenv) anupamkumar@m1 lib % date && python3 t.py>1 && perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /searchListZpids\",\"\[((.*?))\]\"/' html.txt>2 && diff 1 2 && rm html.txt 1 2
Thu Jan 27 13:08:19 EST 2022
```

Comment: I've run the script a few times since I created this post and I ran it just now. The result most of the time differs.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all right and you are mistaken thinking that you are getting an incorrect list of zpids.

This list of zpids is a list of agent listings that are displayed on the current page (in your case 9th page, because you are using the `9_p` route in your URL).

In fact, you have more than 5000 agent listings according to your request and you are even not specifying the order of these agent listings, so they can differ from request to request (and you should see it in your browser too).

You can try to set sorting in your request. For example, [this](https://www.zillow.com/ct/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22CT%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-75.3118282890625%2C%22east%22%3A-70.2031857109375%2C%22south%22%3A40.65842390445305%2C%22north%22%3A42.33689829075037%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A8%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A11%2C%22regionType%22%3A2%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22pricea%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D) URL shows agent listings sorted by price from low to high. But it is not the full solution to your problem too, because the full list of objects can always change on the source website.